# Git rebase non-interactive for last two commits - write a batch file

Tags: git, batch-file, rebase

Please help me to write a batch file for `git rebase` which unites two last commits: `HEAD` and `HEAD~1` in current branch into one without using interactive editor.

Assume that both commits have single parent and are not pushed yet.

```
a683ec1 Not pushed 2
c7b480a Not pushed 1
f0e81fb Pushed
```

I want to leave "Pushed" commit and one commit behind it that will contain "Not pushed 1" + "Not pushed 2" in a final state of "Not pushed 2".

Comment: Do you really need a _batch_ (`.bat` or `.cmd`, for interpreting with `cmd.exe`) or would any kind of script do? Git always requires POSIX shell, even on Windows, and that is a much more pleasant environment to script.

Comment: Do you intend to write commit message manually, provide a short commit message as argument, use message of first commit, use message of second commit or concatenate the commit messages (handling the commit message seems to be the most involved part of the procedure, actually).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to squash a number of commits non-interactively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275508/is-there-a-way-to-squash-a-number-of-commits-non-interactively)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea would be to do a:

```
git reset --soft @~ # reset HEAD, preserve current working tree and index
git commit --amend -m "squash HEAD and HEAD~"
```

That doesn't address the commit messages though: the one from `ORIG_HEAD` would be lost.
[torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) addresses that [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949291/git-rebase-non-interactive-for-last-two-commits-write-a-batch-file/23949665#comment36896304_23949665).

If you have multiple commits to squash (since `origin/master`), what you can do is (supposing you don't have any work in progress):

```
echo "squash everything since origin/master" > /tmp/msg
git log  --format=%B origin/master~3.. >> /tmp/msg
git reset --soft origin/master
git commit -F /tmp/msg
```

This time, you don't amend the commit you reset to (since origin/master was already pushed), but you create a new one.

Comment: Doesn't `git reset --hard` lose commits? Is amend better than rebase?

Comment: @Paul I have edited the answer: I want to preserve the current working tree, but reset the index and `HEAD` to `HEAD~`. Then I add everything, and amend the current commit, leaving a `HEAD~` (now new `HEAD`) with all the modifications that were in `ORIG_HEAD`.

Comment: Thank you for the script, it works, but with one problem: It works only the first time. If I execute this batch repeatedly I am expecting to see one commit fewer in `git log --oneline` but am seeing the same amended commit and commit before it. (Yes, there are more than two commits before pushed one).

Comment: @Paul strange, considering `HEAD` is always reset to `HEAD~`

Comment: @Paul "Yes, there are more than two commits before pushed one": you can reset `HEAD` to `HEAD~n`, with `n` being the number of commit to squash. Thay way, no need to repeat the script.

Comment: It would actually be easier to *keep* the index. Because the `git add -A` might add things that were _not_ versioned in `ORIG_HEAD`.

Comment: @VonC: yes, I can do so, can list `git log` and count comments manually but would like to have an easy-to use batch file with as few input parameters as possible. Ideally - with one parameter - comment. Then I could execute it again and again until I come down to desired commit.

Comment: @Paul why counting the commits manually? What has been pushed is referenced by `origin/master`. I have edited my answer to avoid that.

Comment: @JanHudec indeed. In that case, I don't think any `git add` is needed.

Comment: @VonC: Indeed, `git add` is not needed. And not desired.

Comment: Also, you can gather up all the original log messages of the to-be-squashed commits using `git log origin/master..` before doing the `git reset --soft` (add any formatting desired).  Save to a temporary file, use as template or message for new commit.